# What does "grouped by element" mean in numpy.argwhere documentation?

Tags: python, numpy

Numpy argwhere documentation says:

```
def argwhere(a):
    """
    Find the indices of array elements that are non-zero, grouped by element.
    ...
```

However the actual implementation is just

```
return transpose(nonzero(a))
```

So no reordering or grouping is performed.

I would expect that

```
import numpy as np
x = np.full((2,3),6)
x[:,1] = 5
np.argwhere(x)
```

would return

```
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 2]])
```

Instead it returns

```
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2]])
```

Am I missing something or is it a bug in the documentation?

Comment: [0,1] is the indices for one element of the array.  [1,1] is for the next nonzero element.  Don't try to read anything profound in that phrasing.  It's just trying to contrast it with the tuple of arrays that `np.nonzero` returns.  In `nonzero` the "grouping" is by dimension.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks. Could you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[0,1]` is the indices for one element of the array. `[1,1]` is for the next nonzero element. Don't try to read anything profound in that phrasing. It's just trying to contrast it with the tuple of arrays that `np.nonzero` returns. In `nonzero` the "grouping" is by dimension.